# Fee logic for online shop

Tags: knockout.js, coffeescript

Can anyone please help me with one thing.

I have some sort of online shop, and when user place his item,it appears two fields.

The first one is **price** (`the one that user will receive when item will be sold`) and the second one is **buyPrice** (`the one that another user will pay for this item`), the difference between them is fee (`equal to 0.08`).

I have problem when buyPrice less or equal to `0.07` because price won't change. I use to fix function to deal with float numbers.

Here is js code:

```
@baseFee = window.app.fee

@fee = (val) ->
  if +val <= 0.07 then 0.6 else @baseFee
@price = ko.observable('').extend({ throttle: 150 })
@buyPrice = ko.observable('').extend({ throttle: 150 })

@price.subscribe =>
  price = +@price()
  @updateBuyPrice price if price > 0

@buyPrice.subscribe =>
  buyPrice = +@buyPrice()
  @updatePrice buyPrice if buyPrice > 0

@updatePrice = (buyPrice) =>
  price = +@price()
  newPrice = (buyPrice - buyPrice * @fee(buyPrice)).toFixed(2)
  newBuyPrice = (price + price * @fee(buyPrice)).toFixed(2)
  @price newPrice if buyPrice != +newBuyPrice

@updateBuyPrice = (price) =>
  buyPrice = +@buyPrice()
  newPrice = (buyPrice - buyPrice * @fee(price)).toFixed(2)
  newBuyPrice = (price + price * @fee(price)).toFixed(2)
  @buyPrice newBuyPrice if price != +newPrice
```

And here is html where I apply this:

```
.form-group.pull-left
  label for="price" You will get:
  div data-bind="css: selectedItem().priceCssClass()"
    .input-group-addon= Settings[:app][:currency][:sign]
    input.form-control type="number" step="0.01" id="price" data-bind="value: selectedItem().price, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"
 .form-group.pull-left
   label for="buy-price" Buyer will pay:
   div data-bind="css: selectedItem().buyPriceCssClass()"
     .input-group-addon= Settings[:app][:currency][:sign]
     input.form-control type="number" step="0.01" id="buy-price" data-bind="value: selectedItem().buyPrice, valueUpdate: '"
```

The thing is when i choose buyPrice as `0.08` this logic do some extra loop because the price will be equal to `0.08 - 0.08 * 0.08 = 0.07`, so the fee value will be changed from `0.08` to `0.6` due to @fee function.

I don't know how to fix this or maybe I should change logic.

So I will be greatfull for any help.

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of subscriptions, you might want to use a writable computed. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717905/how-can-i-get-two-computed-values-to-bind-to-each-other

Comment: @RoyJ Ok, thanks, I'll try this.