# KnockoutJS - two way binding adapter - avoid cycles

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

A lot of times in knockout I come at the following situation:

I have an observable, and I want to create a two way binding adapter between the observables A and B, i.e. if A changes, change B and if B changes, then change A.

```
        +-------------+         +-------------+         +-------------+
        |     A       |  -----> |  Adapter    |  -----> |      B      |
        |  Observable |  <----- |             |  <----- |  Observable |
        +-------------+         +-------------+         +-------------+
```

At first this seems like a DON'T DO because this creates a cyclic dependency, BUT in the end this exactly what happens when you bind a GUI element to an observable. Imagine your have an existing binding, but you want to change its binding result, without touching the binding itself.

Lets look at an example ([jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/domoran/z9m6k8tm/)):

**HTML:**

```
<body>
   <p data-bind="text: 'Value:' + val()"></p>
   <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: val"></input>
   <p data-bind="text: 'Value 2:' + val2()"></p>
   <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: val2"></input>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  this.val = ko.observable("");
  this.val2 = ko.observable("");

  this.val.subscribe(function () {
    console.log("VAL Changed!");
    self.val2(self.val().toUpperCase());   
  });

  this.val2.subscribe(function() {
    console.log("VAL2 Changed!");
    self.val(self.val2().toLowerCase());   
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

You will notice, that when you type something in the first textbox a cycle is triggered:

- The binding changes val
- the subscribe to val fires and changes val2
- the subscribe to val2 fires and changes val
- knockout surpresses to run the subscribe for val again (cycle detection)

The result is here that if you type an Uppercase letter in the first input box, it will be immediately converted to a lowercase letter, by the 2nd subscribe and vice versa.

While this seems nice in this example, it can result in very hard to find bugs. A simple way to resolve the problem would now be, to have a flag inside the binding, that will avoid the update when we are inside the update of the other side:

([jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/domoran/ydtxdfw2/))

```
 ....
 var flag = false; 
  this.val.subscribe(function () {
    if (flag) return; 
    flag = true; 
    self.val2(self.val().toUpperCase());
    flag = false; 
  });

  this.val2.subscribe(function() {
    if (flag) return; 
    flag = true; 
    self.val(self.val2().toLowerCase());
    flag = false; 
  });
  ....
```

Now when you change the second input, it will not "fire back" but only fire in one direction.

**Now finally my question:**

- Is the adapter an invalid use case and does it hint to a conceptual problem with the code?
- How would you go about preventing the cylce? With a flag like in my example? Maybe using throtteling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is one actual data item and two computeds to present it as either upper- or lowercase. The trick is that the computeds need to be writable. Their write functions can just write directly to the underlying data item, because its case doesn't matter.

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  this.val = ko.observable("");

  this.val1 = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function() {
      return self.val().toLowerCase();
    },
    write: function(newVal) {
      self.val(newVal);
    }
  });
  this.val2 = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function() {
      return self.val().toUpperCase();
    },
    write: function(newVal) {
      self.val(newVal);
    }
  });

  this.val1.subscribe(function() {
    console.log("VAL Changed!");
  });

  this.val2.subscribe(function() {
    console.log("VAL2 Changed!");
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p data-bind="text: 'Value:' + val1()"></p>
  <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: val1" />
  <p data-bind="text: 'Value 2:' + val2()"></p>
  <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: val2" />
</body>
```

Comment: This does not resolve the effect of the cyclic dependency. If you run your code snippet you will realize, that when typing a lowercase letter to the second input it will be immediately be converted to an uppercase letter by the first subscription firing back.

Comment: The subscriptions do not do any conversion. There is no cycle. Both computeds' `read` values change when the underlying data item changes, and that's all.

Comment: Ah sorry - I did not take the proper time to understand your solution. So you are saying there are situations where both ends of the "adapter" only represent 'one' value. There is a difference to the above solution, which allows both ends of the adapter to have a different state, while in your case there is only one state 'val' on which both ends of the adapter depend. This seems to me even cleaner, than Matthews solution. Do you think that there might be situations where the solution with 2 states might be more applicable? Cannot wrap my brain around it fully yet.

Comment: As a general principle, you should not have redundant states. If two things move together, they are a shared state with different representations, and one of them should be a computed.
[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30718582/392102) of two states plus a computed that model three interrelated variables.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following method in similar situations.  I think it's clean and you don't have to worry about managing the state of your variable with the flag.

Basically, make use of writeable observables, and create a backing observable for each inter-dependent item to store its state, then use the writeable observable to deal with the logic as to what should happen when to other observables when that value changes.

So, your viewmodel would look like this:

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.val = ko.observable("");
  self.val2 = ko.observable("");

  self.valComputed = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function () { return self.val(); },
    write: function (value) {
        self.val(value);
        self.val2(value.toUpperCase());
    }
  });

  self.val2Computed = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function () { return self.val2(); },
    write: function (value) {
        self.val2(value);
        self.val(value.toLowerCase());
    }
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

And you would change your HTML to bind to the computed observables, like this:

```
<body>
   <p data-bind="text: 'Value:' + valComputed()"></p>
   <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: valComputed"></input>
   <p data-bind="text: 'Value 2:' + val2Computed()"></p>
   <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: val2Computed"></input>
</body>
```

I hope that helps! :-)

Comment: Aah my brain hurts ... :-)  The difference in behaviour to real observables would be that writing to val2Computed would not be reflected in its own value. Do you think it would be save to add 'self.val2(value);' to the write handler of val2Computed and also 'self.val(value);' to the write Handler of valComputed to make sure, that the computeds would behave like real observables when binding to them? See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/domoran/L28p2ssd)

Comment: Ah yes, of course.  Good catch!  You'd definitely want to store the value of the observable that is being set.  I edited it, adding in those lines.