# knockout observablearray with computed function read and write

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am just new learner about knockout.js. My single page application will have a table that data bind with many records. Each row of table will have 2 input that is requsted count and requested amount after data bind. 
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfdm4.png)

The 2 input in each row of table is writable with computed function that have below situation:

1. When enter value in input requested count, requested amount on input will be display immediately(requested count Multiplying denom value ).

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozmqm.png)

2. When enter value in input requested amount, requested count on input should bbe display automatically(input requested amount divided by denom value) but failed to display.

[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paVhO.png)

Now my problem is after requested amount key in, the requested count is not display successful, but first scenario is successful

Below is my code:

`enter code here`

```
function Model(noteValue, noteCount) {
    var self = this;
    this.denom = ko.observable(noteValue);
    this.available = ko.observable(noteCount);
    this.requestedCount = ko.observable(); 
    this.CMCurrencyCode = ko.observable("MYR");
    this.CMDispensedAmount = ko.observable(0.00); 

    self.RequestedAmount = ko.pureComputed( {
        read: function () {

            return parseFloat(self.denom() * self.requestedCount()).toFixed(2).toLocaleString();

        },
        write: function (val) {

            ReqCount = parseFloat(val) / parseFloat(self.denom());

            self.requestedCount(ReqCount);
        }
    });
}

    function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.ArrayOfCassettes([]);

    this.GetConfiguration = function () {
         //browse to server to get data
         var uri = 'http://localhost/tcrwebapi/;

         $.getJSON(uri)
         .done(function (data) {
            myObj = data["param"];

            for (m in myObj[i]["Denomination"]["lpCurrencies"]) {
               denom = parseInt(myObj[i]["denom"]["currency"][m]["denomvalue"]);

               available = parseInt(myObj[i]["denom"]["currency"][m]["available"]);
            }
           self.ArrayOfCassettes.push(new Model(denom, available));
     }

 }
```

Below is my UI:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-sm">
<thead class="thead-default">
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center;"> Currency </th>
        <th style="text-align: right;"> Denom </th>
        <th style="text-align: right;"> Available </th>
        <th style="text-align: right;"> Requested Count</th>
        <th style="text-align: right;"> Requested Amount</th>
        <th style="text-align: right;"> Dispensed Amount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: ArrayOfCassettes()">
    <tr>
        <td class="success" style="text-align: center;" data-bind="text: CMCurrencyCode"></td>
        <td class="success" style="text-align: right;" data-bind="text: denom"></td>
        <td class="success" style="text-align: right;" data-bind="text: available"></td>
        <td class='success' style="text-align: right;" ">
            <input type="number"  data-bind="numeric, value: CMAutoDispenseCounter, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />

        </td>

        <td class='success' style="text-align: right;" data-bind="visible: CMDisplayInput">
            <input type="text"  data-bind="numeric, value: CMAutoDispenseAmount(), valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
        </td>
        <td class="success" style="text-align: right;" data-bind="text: CMDispensedAmount()"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Thanks

Comment: It would really help if you could make a small example that only includes code relevant to what you are asking about.

Comment: Also, this might be what you're asking about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717905/how-can-i-get-two-computed-values-to-bind-to-each-other

Comment: Thanks, i found my problem d which is my mistake. after remove bracket from CMAutoDispenseAmount(), now it is showing.